# How to enable / disable administrative share from remote, using Active directory management tools?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Is it possible to enable or disable remote PC administrative share (like c$ and d$), using Active Directory management tools?

Answer (score 0):

You can add registry entry with GP editor to policy for selected computers.

`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\`

`AutoShareWks` `dword` `0`